# Physics simulation stops at frame 250

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I am working on a gravity simulation in Blender of objects falling to the ground. The frame period starts from 1 to 250, and I started the gravity simulation by clicking "play". I somehow changed the end frame period to 300, and the gravity simulation that I did earlier just ended at 250, and I wanted it to continue to 300.

Look at the bottom of the sequence of the interface. You could see that orange line in that sequence area where the simulation took place. Once it goes over the orange line at the end, the simulation stops and it continues on to the end of the frame sequence.

Does anybody know how I can continue the simulation through the rest of the sequence?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

By default simulations cache only form frame 1 to 250, you can change that in the scene >Rigid Body World > Cache

[image]